# Typehint generic type variable

Tags: python, python-3.9

How can I typehint that something should have the same type as earlier?

```py
def mymap(xs: [T], func: T -> V): -> [V]:
    return [func(x) for x in xs]
```

Comment: `def mymap(xs: Iterable[T], func: Callable[[T], V]) -> list[V]: ...` should work? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)

```
from typing import Callable, List, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V')


def mymap(items: List[T], fn: Callable[[T], V]) -> List[V]:
    return [fn(e) for e in items]
```

Comment: do I have to use `List` and `Callable` too?

Comment: It depends on what `items` really is and which version of Python you're using. You should definitely use `Callable` but `List` could be replaced by `Set` or `Dict` for example. If you're using (I think) Python 3.9+ you can use `list` directly instead of `typing.List`.